# "Index and length must refer to a location within the string" error

Tags: c#, string, indexing

I am trying to extract the first 200 words of a string and sometimes I get the following error:

```
"Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"
```

The code is:

```
int i = GetIndex(fullarticle, 200);
string result = fullarticle.Substring(0, i);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You say that you want 200 words. What happen if your string has less than 200 words? Could you show the code of GetIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears safe to assume the error is coming from [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).  Given that you get this error when `startIndex + length > given.Length` or `startIndex < 0` or `length < 0`, `GetIndex` is either returning a value greater than `fullarticle.Length` or a negative number.  The error exists in `GetIndex` so if you wish to carry on with the code you have, you should post the code of `GetIndex` to get the best answer.

If you're up for something different, you could try this:

```
static string GetShortIntroduction(string phrase, int words)
{
    // simple word count assuming spaces represent word boundaries
    return string.Join(" ", phrase.Split().Take(words));
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It goes out of range as your string is shorter than 200 characters

To remedy you could use `Math.Min` it will pick the lower value between string length and 200.

```
fullarticle.Substring(0, Math.Min(fullarticle.Length, 200));
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because the string has less than 200 words in it and likely coming from `GetIndex` return a value for `i` greater than the number of characters in `fullarticle`. As an example of the error

```
"s".Substring(0,2)
```

throws

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length

If your intent is to get up to the first 200 words in a string, you would need to check

1. The string is not null
2. The number of words in the string; if it's less than 200 words, that should be your maximum index, otherwise use 200.
3. substring based on 2.

Comment: I lowered it to 150 and I am still getting: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Comment: The code isn’t attempting to get 200 characters, it’s attempting to get 200 *words*. Also, your method for resolving the error is bad, see my comment on Steve’s answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph my bad, I incorrectly assumed that the OP meant characters :) Updated. In relation to **hiding** the error, I think it depends upon the intent behind what the method is doing and assumptions that can be made about the inputs. In some cases, I agree that hiding the error may be bad, in others I don't :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i is larger than the whole fullarticle length. Check your GetIndex function.